# Angular: using location to change URL; how to stop new URL being pushed in the history stack?

Tags: javascript, angular, location

I have a component which has multiple mat-tabs; clicking on one tab should remove all query parameters and add that tab name = true as a parameter; ie if I click on payments the url should change from `http://localhost:4200/tab` to `http://localhost:4200/tab?payments=true`.

The component I am trying to edit is very large and takes a long time for initialisation, so when I use router.navigate() with all the required parameters, it reloads the whole component again, which is not a good option.

Another option I found was `location.go()` which does not reload the component but changes the url, which I require but every time a different tab is clicked, the new updated URl gets pushed into the history stack. Is there any way to change the URL without adding an entry to the stack?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid URLs to be pushed to the stack? This browser behavior exists for a reason. It's usually not a good practice (from UX perspective) to intervene in these mechanisms.

Comment: First question: Why do you want to change the URL without switching the component?
Second question: Can you separate the component into many smaller components?
Third question: "which does not reload the component but changes the url, which I require". Do you want to reload the component or not?

Comment: @ytan11 I want to change the url to go to that specific tab when clicked; Yes component can be seperated into many smaller components but will take a long time; 3) I do not want to reload the component as I mentioned in the second paragraph

Comment: @FabianStrathaus when switching tabs the URL gets changed like ```http://localhost:4200/task?payments=true``` and ```http://localhost:4200/task?overview=true```; multiple tab switches would add many of these URLs to the history stack after which using the browser back button just navigates through the same component multiple times.

Comment: I am confused what you meant by "tabs". A component? A bootstrap/material tab?
If it is a component, you can simply use ngIf/ngSwitch with ng-container/ng-template to show/hide the component without needing the URL.
If it is a bootstrap/material tab, I don't even think it make sense.

Comment: Besides that, you really should separate them into smaller components. Not only does it helps with maintanence and readability, it probably will help in performance in your case.

Comment: @ytan11 I already specified mat-tabs, a material version of a nav element. I am adding it to the URL because I want to open that tab when the page gets refreshed. (this is a requirement from the company). The component is very large, and cannot be refactored as of now.

Comment: @SteveChacko I see. My bad. I don't know how you can stop the history to be pushed, but maybe you can use local storage instead.